# How to disable antivirus and enable windows defender using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, virus

How to firstly disable antivirus from computer and enable windows defender using powershell command:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false
```

I'm performing this command to enable the windows defender but due to inbuilt antivirus I'm not able to enable it and perform this operation:

```
Start-MpScan -ScanType QuickScan -ScanPath C
```

If there is having another scan command for powershell which is not conflicting of having another antivirus then suggest me or help me to get the solution of above problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all.. go to your older questions and mark the answers as correct when they helped you..

Comment: Second, if you could disable your antivirus with a simple powershell command, the antivirus would be pretty terrible at its job...

Answer (score 0):

**If** the AV software exposes an API/CLI facility to disable it, you will need to find that from the AV company as they are all generally different.

You could uninstall the AV software, but it may not be silent about it, in other words the uninstall software may have prompts the user has to deal with before it uninstalls often requiring a reboot before you could run the windows defender scan, before you then have to reinstall the AV software. If it could uninstall/install silently, that might be a work around?

Another possible way would be to get handles to the AV software, walk through (enumerate) the screen controls and post events to the controls to simulate a user, but this is getting more into coding than scripting, and you still may not be able to walk through the controls, for example some web browsers dont let you enumerate the address bar in order to post web addresses into them and hijack them that way.